# User.find() related error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

### Error: data and hash arguments required

Of course this question has been asked already. But my problem is different. I am trying to login with **username - lucky** and **password - mani** which is already registered into the mongodb. But my project is not working properly. Here its **userroutes.js** is given below.

```
router.post('/login',(request,response)=>{
console.log(request.body.form_username);//lucky
console.log(request.body.form_password)//mani
userOperation.login(response,request);});
```

Here I am getting username and password on the console.
Now it's calling **userOperation.login**. Here is the **usercrud.js** in which **userOperation.login** is implemented.
`

```
var User = require("../../schema/user/userschema");

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userOperation={

    login(res,request){
       console.log(request.body.form_username);//lucky
       console.log(request.body.form_password);//mani

              User.findOne({ userid:request.body.form_username}, function (err, user) {
                console.log(request.body.form_username);//undefined....why???
                console.log(request.body.form_password);//undefined....why???
                if (err) {

                     return done(err); }
                if (!user) {

                  return done(null, false, { message: 'no user found' });
                }
                if(user){
                bcrypt.compare(request.body.form_username, user.password, function(err, res) {

                    if (err)
                    throw err;
                    if(!res) {

                      console.log('Ooops!. Wrong Pass!');
                      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
                    }
                    if(res){
                        // request.session.userid = request.body.form_username;
                        // request.sesssion.password = request.body.form_password;
                    response.send("Login Done");
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            },
        }`
```

Still username and password is being printed properly but here **problems starts--**
When I am trying to print username and password inside the **User.find()**, it's printing **undefind**. **why??????**
This is why I am getting the **Error: data and hash arguments required**
Because I am trying to give an undefined argument into the **bcrypt.compare()**

[this is link of screenshot of the server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFWgI.png)

My second question is **why I am getting undefined four times after the server starts??**
Here is the userschema.js

`var mongoose = require("../../connection");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({userid:String,
                             password:String

                            });
var User = mongoose.model("onlineusers",userSchema);
module.exports = User;`

Answer (score 0):

hey friend can please let me know your userschema.

and if you are using node -v above 7.10.0 then use

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

if it possible then try this i have done same thing

```
 try{
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, user) {
      if (err){ 
        return res.status(500).send('Error on the server.');
      }
      if (!user){
         return res.status(404).send('No user found.');}

      // check if the password is valid
      var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
      if (!passwordIsValid){
        console.log(passwordIsValid);
         logger.error(req.baseUrl + "status 401 auth faill: "+ req.body.email);
         return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, token: null })
        }
      else{
      // if user is found and password is valid
      // create a token
      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
      });

      // return the information including token as JSON
      logger.info("status 200 auth success: "+ req.body.email);
      res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });
    }
    });  
  }catch(ex){
    logger.error('Login erro '+ ex)
    console.log(ex);
    throw ex;
```

Also use for proper body parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Let me know if need more help Happy to help:)

And please ignore token part.

Comment: hey friend I have given userschema.js .

Comment: I am pretty much sure about body parser. Its correct. That's why I am able to print username and password on the console